# print preview doesnt match with html layout

Tags: html, layout, printing

im trying to print a mail that i made in html (school homework), this is my html layout 
[image]

and this is my print preview[image]

i already tried using @page in css, but it doesnt work

```
@page :right {
margin: 10.8cm;
```

Answer (score -1):

> @page is not supported in Firefox, but supported in Chrome 2.0+, IE 8.0+, Opera 6.0+ and Safari 5.0+.
>
> @page :first is supported only in IE8+ and Opera 9.2+.

Comment: "@page is not supported in Firefox" — [@page is supported by Firefox](https://caniuse.com/#search=page)

Comment: "it might due to explorer" — The screenshot is of Chrome